# How you make a winforms app look like blend (using colour schemes)?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a winforms project. At present my gui is a series of grey forms. Does anyone have any examples of how to make a winforms app look like a 'blend' style black/shades of dark grey app?

Thanks

Comment: I believe Expression Blend is completely written in [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx).

Comment: Spend two decades listening to Bauhaus prior to choosing your colour palette?

Answer (score 0):

While @dtb is right in that Blend uses WPF, you can get Blend-like background effects by setting your window style to `AllPaintingInWmPaint` and drawing a gradient for window or control backgrounds. For example, in your Form initialization:

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
```

Then override OnPaintBackground:

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground (System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle rDisplay = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
    using (LinearGradientBrush lgb = new LinearGradientBrush(rDisplay, Color.WhiteSmoke, Color.SteelBlue, LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(lgb, rDisplay);
    }
}
```

Comment: since when a windows Form has a BackgroundStyle property ?

Comment: @Stefan, sorry, that should have been `ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint`.

Comment: Just set the DoubleBuffered property to true in the constructor.  That covers the required ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer as well.